# Why does a Process.Start shell command fail with "unterminated quoted string" in Linux?

Tags: c#, shell, 7zip, ash

#### The problem

I am trying to run 7z from C# code to extract some files. The command works under Windows or if I just run it from the shell directly, but not from code. Maybe it's not the exact same, and I don't realize it.

So I'm doing this:

```cs
//Unpack dump with 7z
StringBuilder argument = new($"\"{Config.zipPath}\" x \"{dumpPath}\" -so | \"{Config.zipPath}\" x -y -si -ttar");
foreach (string file in new[] { "vn", "vn_titles" /* and other strings */ }) {
    argument.Append($" db/{file} db/{file}.header");
}
Process.Start(Config.shell, string.Format(Config.arguments, argument)).WaitForExit();
```

The config file is a list of key=value pairs that get loaded into the static `Config` class. So, it works for Windows:

```
shell=cmd.exe
zipPath=C:/Program Files/7-Zip-Zstandard/7z.exe
arguments=/C "{0}"
```

but not for Linux:

```
shell=ash
zipPath=7z
arguments=-c '{0}'
```

The ash command there fails with an error:
`x: line 0: syntax error: unterminated quoted string`

---

#### Some things I've tried / checked

- The C# code runs without error, at least up until it needs to access the unpacked files which aren't there.
- `Config.shell` is `ash`
- `string.Format(Config.arguments, argument)` is `-c '"7z" x "dump.tar.zst" -so | "7z" x -y -si -ttar db/vn db/vn.header db/vn_titles db/vn_titles.header db/releases db/releases.header db/releases_titles db/releases_titles.header db/releases_vn db/releases_vn.header db/vn_length_votes db/vn_length_votes.header db/tags db/tags.header db/tags_parents db/tags_parents.header db/tags_vn db/tags_vn.header'`
- Based on the previous two points, I would assume the command that gets executed is the concatenation of those two, that is, `ash -c '"7z" x "dump.tar.zst" -so | "7z" x ... '`, and that command, ran manually, works as expected. So I'm really having trouble figuring out where the problem comes from.

---

#### The non-ideal found solution

The answer provided by knittl should be correct, as far as I understand. Whether Windows or Linux, the shell should be called with 2 arguments - `-c` (or `/C` for Windows' `cmd`) and then the command I want to run, which is correctly the `argument` string. This is generally the simpler method. But it doesn't work under Windows.

`cmd` does not seem to support spaces in path names inside the argument to `\C`, at all. Not enclosing them in quotation marks fails to recognize them as a single string, and enclosing them in quotation marks makes the path invalid, as quotation marks are not part of the path.

`powershell` doesn't have this problem, but it has a limit of 256 characters for the argument of `-c`, also making my command unusable.

So the solution is to detect which OS I'm on via `Environment.OSVersion.Platform`, and either pass the arguments as a string array for Unix, or use the special feature of the `cmd /C` command for Win32NT, where it doesn't actually parse the whole command if the first character of the command is a `"`, but instead just strips that and the last character if it's also a `"`, saving me from escaping those characters inside the command, which is the only reason my initial version worked at all.

Comment: The command executed is "probably" (I don't know how `Process.Start` splits the argument list) `'ash' '-c' \''"7z"' 'x' '"dump.tar.zst"' '-so' …` (many many words) and so on, while it must be `'ash' '-c' '"7z" x "dump.tar.zst" -so …'` (exactly 3 words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-c '...'` must be two arguments exactly (`-c` and whatever is inside the quotes). I'm not sure how the `Process.Start(string, string)` overloads splits the second parameter into command line arguments, but from your question it looks like it is not splitting them as one (or your shell) would expect :)

You want to call the overload [`Start(string, IEnumerable<string>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-8.0#system-diagnostics-process-start(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string)))):

```
Process.Start(Config.shell, new[]{ "-c",  argument })
```

Comment: Good to know that overload exists. That does solve the problem for my Linux, but now the escaping is somehow wrong for Windows. `'\"C:/Program Files/7-Zip-Zstandard/7z.exe\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command ...`

Comment: @Torn get rid of the quotes. The argument to your external program is `C:\Program Files\...` and not `"C:\Program Files\..."` (and definitely not `'\"C:\Program Files\...\"'`). It ca be quite tricky to get the context right here, but quotes you type in your shell are never part of the arguments.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but without the quotes it can't handle the space, i.e. `'C:\Program' is not recognized ...`. I'll poke around a while at variations, see what works. It's significantly easier for me to debug the Windows version.

Comment: @Tom with the overload, spaces shouldn't be a problem. Are you using the overload or still the original version?

Comment: I am using the overload. So, `Process.Start(Config.shell, new[] { "/C", argument.ToString() })` with argument being `StringBuilder argument = new($"{Config.zipPath} x {dumpPath} -so | {Config.zipPath} x -y -si -ttar");` etc.

Comment: @Tom you can also try looking into `ProcessStartInfo` class, perhaps it helps you a bit with escaping?